# What is $\overline{B_{R}(x)}$

Tags: functional-analysis, notation

In functional analysis, I have found that $$B_{R}(x):=\{y \in X: ||x-y||<R\}$$

I have now come across a variation of this, $\overline{B_{R}(x)}$. I can't find a definition for this. What does the bar mean?

Comment: closure of the set.  You should be able to find it defined in just about any introductory real analysis text book, probably in the metric spaces chapter :)  (i.e. $\{y\in X \mid \|x-y\| \leq R \}$

Comment: Looks like sphere in normed space, center in $x$ and radius $R$ and its closure.

Comment: Thank you! @postmortes

Comment: Notation has its problems.  Does it mean the closure of the open ball of radius $R$  (as it seems), or the closed ball of radius $R$.  Sometimes I write $\overline{B}_R(x)$ for the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely it is the closure of the set $B_R(x)$. Although unlikely, it is also possible that it denotes the closed ball
$$\{y \in X: \Vert x-y \Vert \leq R\}$$

In general, the closed ball and the closure of the open ball do not coincide, so that's something you have to be careful for.